# Opening a Windows application through php's `exec`

Tags: php, windows, exec

You have a `php` web application installed on a Windows desktop machine and used locally.

How could you open an application (say `notepad.exe`) when the user accesses a specific webpage ?

Of course, `exec` works for command-line applications, but not for graphical ones, since the commands are executed as the php/apache user.

So the question could be rephrased as **How can one use `exec` as a different user ?**

Comment: Windows has a `runas` command for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, it was much more simple than what I thought.

You just have to tick "*Allow this service to interact with desktop*" for Apache's service in the services configuration panel and applications opened though php will be opened for the user.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to open notepad.exe from your webserver for the current user.

I doubt that is ever going to work as PHP is run as a different user. This also means the webserver has to be installed on and run from the PC the person is using.

What you can do is have the browser open notepad. Associate the file extension to notepad in your browser ("Always open this type of file with ..." or something along those lines).